# How to change font-size of printable div

Tags: jquery, html, css, printing

how can i change the font-style of the div i wwant to print?

this is the styling

```
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 0;
}
@media print {
    .page {
        margin: 0;
        border: initial;
        border-radius: initial;
        width: initial;
        min-height: initial;
        box-shadow: initial;
        background: initial;
        page-break-after: always;
    }
    html, body {
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
html, body {
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;
        font-size: 1mm;
    }
```

i tried everything the font-size is not getting smaller what am i doing wrong? 
Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. You should be able to see the changes in the print preview window. If you don't see the changes try adding `!important` to the css rule.

```
@media print {
 div {
   font-size: 1mm;
/*   font-size: 1mm !important;*/
  }

 /*Also move your @page css inside you @media css */
 @page {
     size: A4;
     margin: 0;
  }

}
```